# Update a variable inside ForEach loop

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I simply can't understand why this simple code is not working. My expected output is 10 and 15, but it is returning 2 and 3. That means that the update is not working.

```cs
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

numbers.Add(2);
numbers.Add(3);

numbers.ForEach(n => n = n*5);

numbers.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

Note: I've already searched a lot, but I could not understand this behavior.

How should I fix it?

Update: the same behavior for strings.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("a");
strings.Add("b");

strings.ForEach(s => s = s + "--");

strings.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Comment: This is because integers are value types and are pass by value not by reference.

Comment: I'm getting the same using strings. I can't modify a string inside the ForEach loop.

Comment: @Ricardo Really? What operation are you performing?

Comment: @Ricardo .NET strings are immutable - they can't be changed once created.  Any time you modify a string, you're actually creating a new, modified copy of that string.

Comment: @Ricardo String are immutable but if you do pass other reference types, it works as expected , you can see my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`n` is a copy of your current value in the list not a reference to your value.If you want to manipulate the values in your list then use a for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<numbers.Count; i++)
    numbers[i] *= 5;
```

---

More detailed explanation:

With a normal `foreach` loop your code doesn't even compile:

```
foreach(var n in numbers)
      n = n * 5; // Readonly local variable cannot be used as an assignment target
```

Remember that `List<T>.ForEach` loop is not the same as `foreach` but it is just a method that takes a `Action<int>` delegate as argument and performs the specified action on the each element in your list.So it performs something like this (taken from the source code):

```
 public void ForEach(Action<T> action) 
 {
     // removed unnecessary parts for brevity
     for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) 
     {
         action(_items[i]);
     }
 }
```

As you can see here the `_item[i]` is passed to the action and since int is a value types the copy of your value is passed rather than a reference.And that's why your values didn't change.

For strings: Apart from the fact that strings are immutable, assigning a new reference to a reference type doesn't change the object that holds the same reference.For example consider this:

```
static void Update(string s)
{
     s = "bar";
}

string f = "foo";
Update(f);
Console.WriteLine(f); // foo
```

Assigning a new reference to `s` doesn't change the `f`, `f` stil holds the old reference and `s` is pointing to a new location in memory.This is not because `s` is a copy,it's not.If you change a property of `s` (with strings you can't do that but try with another reference type), it would update the property of `f` as well.It works in this way because `s` and `f` are two different strings that points to the same location in memory.So `s` is not bound to `f`.You can think they were declared like this:

```
string f = "foo";
string s = f;
s  = "bar";
```

The only exception is when you pass `f` as a `ref` argument then the assignment will change the `f` as well:

```
static void Update(ref string s)
{
     s = "bar";
}

string f = "foo";
Update(ref f);
Console.WriteLine(f); // bar
```

Comment: Note that it's the same for reference types if you assign to the variable instead of mutating the value.

Answer (score 4):

Because they are value types, rather than mutating the list you could create a modified one using `Select`

```
var newList= numbers.Select(n => n = n*5);
```

As imperative programmers, we love mutating things, which is not a brilliant idea!! 
The reason why it did not work for strings is that because by default C# passes a copy of the reference rather than the actual reference.

```
void Fn(string s)
{
  s = "not being changed";
}   

Main()
{  
var hello = "hello";
Fn(hello);
Console.WriteLine (hello); // prints hello again!!
}
```

However, if you want to change the reference you have to use the `ref` keyword.

```
void Fn(ref string s)
{
  s = "Unfortunately, changed!";
}   

Main()
{  
var hello = "hello";
Fn(ref hello);
Console.WriteLine (hello); // Unfortunately, changed!!!
}
```

I think that changing parameters' values is a terrible idea and you shouldn't be doing that, you should return a new string that contains the new modifications.

Comment: Ty @Sleiman, that is the best code fix so far (upvoted you), but I still would like to understand better why the ForEach does not work for strings, since they use Reference and not values.

Comment: @Ricardo even when you pass a reference type to function, it passes a copy of the reference and not the actual reference

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because the parameter to the ForEach are passed by value and not by reference.
However, if you do pass a reference type, it must work as expected as shown below

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Frog> numbers = new List<Frog>();

            numbers.Add(new Frog { name = "balcha" });
            numbers.Add(new Frog { name = "Tibara" });
            numbers.ForEach(n => n.name = "Bontu");
            numbers.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n.name));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Frog
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
 Bontu
 Bontu
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure OP didn't just want somebody to fix their code, but to explain what's going on.